# Selecting a printer in .Net

Tags: .net, winforms, printing

I have a win forms app that needs to allow the user to select a printer from the list of installed printers on the PC. Is there a built in dialog or do i have to write a custom dialog ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the built in common dialog ***PrintDialog*** or you can use ***PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters*** to get all the printer names if you want to build your own dialog.

Answer (score 1):

[PrintDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.aspx) is probably what you want.